# Display values from multiple columns to make line graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data that looks like this:

[image: link]

and I want to use ggplot2 make a line graph in which each of these column names appears on the X axis, and each row's values are connected with a line which is colored based on a different column's value in the table. I'm not quite sure how to do this. I'm imagining the graph looking like this:

[image: link]

any help is appreciated.

I've tried using geom_line() but I have no idea how to make it function like this.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You have to reshape your data to long, i.e. try `dat |> tidy::pivot_longer(-set, names_to = "x", values_to = "value") |> ggplot(aes(x, value, color = set, group = set) + geom_line()`. For more help please provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including the code you have tried and a snippet of your data shared using `dput()`.

Comment: ^ `tidyr::pivot_longer`, not `tidy::pivot_longer`...